# RAML trait parameter default value

Tags: raml

When defining a trait in RAML it's possible to parameterize it, e.g.

```
traits:
  - searchable:
      queryParameters:
        query:
          description: Blah blah
          example: <<example>>
```

Has an `<<example>>` parameter which is provided by a resource that *has*  this trait like so:

```
is: [searchable: {example: "exampleValue"}]
```

Is it possible to specify a default value for trait parameters, such that a resource that has the default value can omit the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Just adding the default key should perform what you need:

```
traits:
  - searchable:
      queryParameters:
        query:
          description: Blah blah
          example: <<example>>
          default: "default value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your example, You could add a default key:

```
   query:
     description: Blah blah
     example: <<example>>
     default: value
```